# Cannot read property 'xxxxx' of undefined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i declare a data

`let data = {}`

then i call webservice with promise

```
getUserData().then((res)=>{
   this.setState({
      data : res.data
   })
})
```

in data response

```
data : {
  name : "kangfu",
  surname : "panda"
  address : {
               no : "111",
               road : "332",
               state : "somewhere"
            }
}
```

when i use in render() it display this error

> Cannot read property 'no' of undefined

in render

```
 render() {
    let {data} = this.state
     consol.loe(data.address)  // show address object.  
 return (
    <h1>data.address.no</h1>  // error
 )
```

Comment: You have to consider that at the first `render()` call `this.state.data` might not still have been defined

Answer (score 0):

`render` method is being called when `this.state.data` still have not been defined.

A possible fix might be

```
render() {
  if (!this.state.data) {
    return ("Loading...");
  } else {
    let {data} = this.state
    consol.log(data.address)  // show address object.  
    return (        
      <h1>{data.address.no}</h1>  // error
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside render you have to do something like:

```
if(data === undefined) {
   return <Preloader />; // just an example component
}

return (
   <h1>data.address.no</h1>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your code in a conditional block like so:

```
 render() {
     return (
       {this.state.data &&
       <h1>{this.state.address.no}</h1>
     })
```